# Simple if statement not accurately checking if two values are the same

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape some article titles from a website. I do not want to include "Notes from the Editor" when I run my program, but for some reason this super simple and should be easy if statement on the last two lines isn't working, and still prints out Notes from the Editor. What's wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/american-political-science-review/issue/4061249B1054342207CEF9C50AEC68C5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.findAll('a', class_='part-link')

for result in results:
    if result.text != 'Notes from the Editors':
        print(result.text)
```

Comment: Is the trailing `s` in the string in your code but not in your question a typo?

Comment: What about `if 'Notes from the Editors' not in result.text`?

Comment: The actual tag on that page has a leading and a trailing space.

Comment: Try this, it worked for me : `if result.text.strip() != 'Notes from the Editors'`. Maybe white spaces at the end are causing trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/american-political-science-review/issue/4061249B1054342207CEF9C50AEC68C5")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.findAll('a', class_='part-link')

for result in results:
    if result.text != '\nNotes from the Editors\n':
        print(result.text)
```

its because your if statement doesnt exactly match the if statement. uyou are not considering white spaces or enters. try this.

Comment: More generally, maybe `strip()` the text and then compare against a string without any whitespace at the beginning or the end.